# How to write many-to-many relationships back into MySQL database with sequelize (using node.js, express and vue.js)

Tags: mysql, node.js, vue.js, express, sequelize.js

I created a component catalog (basically a list) for our hardware laboratory with vue.js. The data is stored in a mysql database and handled with node.js, express and sequelize.
The user should be able to assign different locations for a component. Each component can have many locations, each location can have many components.

**What works:** The client receives "components" and their assigned "locations" according to the linking table in the database. This is managed via sequelize's `belongsToMany` function. The database can also be altered and updated

**What doesn't work:** When the user adds a location it gets correctly added to the component variable in vue.js but if the component is updated by the user it only updates the simple data like the name but not the many-to-many relationship between component and location

**TLDR:** Client receives many-to-many relationships from db correctly, but updating them doesn't work

Example of the linking table **component_location** in the mysql database.
[image]

Now the code, first the server with the **location.model.js**:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Location = sequelize.define("location", {
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      details: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
      },
    });
    return Location;
  };
```

The **index.js** with the relevant **belongsToMany** functions

```
db.locations.belongsToMany(db.components, { 
  through: "component_location",
  as: "components",
  foreignKey: "location_id",
});
db.components.belongsToMany(db.locations, {
  through: "component_location",
  as: "locations",
  foreignKey: "component_id",
});
```

The update function in the **component.controller.js**

```
// Update a component by the id in the request
exports.update = (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
  
    Component.update(req.body, {
      where: { id: id }
    })
      .then(num => {
        if (num == 1) {
          res.send({
            message: "Component was updated successfully."
          });
        } else {
          res.send({
            message: `Cannot update component with id=${id}. Maybe component was not found or req.body is empty!`
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message: "Error updating component with id=" + id
        });
      });
  };
```

The router.put function inside **component.routes.js**

```
module.exports = app => {
    const components = require("../controllers/component.controller.js");

    var router = require("express").Router();
    
    // Update a Component with id
    router.put("/:id", components.update);
    
    app.use('/api/components', router);
  };
```

Now the client with update function in the **ComponentDataService.js** that gets referenced inside the vue.js client

```
import http from "../http-common";
class ComponentDataService {  
  update(id, data) {
    return http.put(`/components/${id}`, data);
  }
}
export default new ComponentDataService();
```

Now finally the relevant code from the Component.vue file:
First a quick screenshot including the output in json format from currentComponent.locations if three locations are selected:
[image]

Now the vue code from this multiselect element for locations:

```
         <div class="input-group mb">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <label style="width:120px; font-size:12px; max-height:50px" class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupLocation" >Locations</label>
            <multiselect style="width:320px"  v-model="currentComponent.locations" :options="listOfLocations" :multiple="true" :close-on-select="false" :clear-on-select="false" :preserve-search="false" placeholder="Select Physical Locations" label="name" track-by="name" :preselect-first="false">
              <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ values, search, isOpen }">
                <span class="multiselect__single" v-if="values.length &amp;&amp; !isOpen">{{ values.length }} Physical Location(s) selected</span>
              </template>
            </multiselect> 
          </div>
          <label v-if='debug==1' class="language-json"><code>{{ currentComponent.locations }}</code></label>
        </div>
```

Further down in the code the update button:

```
<b-button style="margin: 10px" type="submit" variant="success" @click="updateComponent">Update</b-button>
```

Relevant code from the script part:

```
<script>
import ComponentDataService from "../services/ComponentDataService";
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
export default {
components: {
    Multiselect,
  },
  name: "component",
  data() {
    return {
      message: '',
      debug: 1,
      currentComponent: null,
      listOfLocations: [],
      submitted: false
    };
  },
    updateComponent() {
      ComponentDataService.update(this.currentComponent.id, this.currentComponent)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },
refreshList() {
      this.retrieveLocations();
    },
},
  mounted() {
    this.getComponent(this.$route.params.id);
    this.retrieveLocations();
  }
};
</script>
```

I hope I managed to show everything of relevance. I would expect that if I add another location in the multiselect and the json code shows that `component.location` is updated, pressing the update button would automatically make sequelize adding the new location id together with the component id to the linking table of component_location. It updates name and type without problems though.

Thanks for your help in advance, I really hope I made this clear, correct me or ask if I could provide better information.

EDIT: I added `console.log(">> req.body", JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2));` to the update function to see how the structure of the received req.body looks like.

Here's the result in the server output when I press UPDATE in the client (looks good to me though and name and type will be update, but the new location won't be added to the join table):

```
>> req.body {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "TestComponent1",
  "type": "Hardware",
  "createdAt": "2022-06-17T12:57:34.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2022-09-05T19:50:18.000Z",
  "locations": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "TestLocation1",
      "details": "Room A1",
      "createdAt": "2022-01-26T21:38:31.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-01-26T21:38:31.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "TestLocation2",
      "details": "Room A2",
      "createdAt": "2022-01-26T21:38:31.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-01-26T21:38:31.000Z"
    }
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "TestLocation3",
      "details": "Room A3",
      "createdAt": "2022-02-02T14:25:04.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-02-02T14:25:04.000Z"
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please also show what you pass in `req.body`

Comment: not sure if I understand the request. You mean what is contained in `req.body` when the server provides the data for the "component" initially or the data that is passed from client via router to the `update` function in `component.controller.js`? I understood that the body is created by sequelize according to the model including the relationships defined by the belongstomany functions

Comment: The second time in `update`

Comment: Ah of course, I added it at the bottom of my post! The data seems correct, therefore I assume the problem lies within the server.

Comment: Probably I made it too complicated. The question is in the end: How can I make sequelize write many-to-many relationship updates into the mysql databse. With the help of the `belongsToMany` functions it can find them and creates a dataset that can be easily read by the client but if the client sends altered data back how can I make it reflect in the join tables for the many-to-many-relationships?

Comment: You also need to use special generated methods for this association

Comment: What kind of methods? I assume you mean something like `Component.addLocation`? But if I have to manually parse each dataset coming from the client and compare it to the dataset that is currently in the database, and then use `addLocation` if there is a difference, then why do I even use sequelize?

Comment: Unfortunately, Sequelize has some limitations that prevents you from updating an entity and its associated records all at once

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm a bit puzzled about this. This means I have to go through the received data in `req.body` and compare it to the data that's still in the database and change the entries in the join tables by hand. Such basic handling of database relationships is exactly what I expected sequelize to do ...

Comment: You can use `setLocations` or something like this to replace all old records by new ones if it's suitable for you